# Passar parametros entre views IOS

Tags: ios, swift

Pessoal tenho uma view onde tenho formas de login no meu app, se a pessoa escolher login ou cadastrar sera redirecionado para a mesma view porem depende do botão que for apertado irei apresentar uma tela diferente...
Como posso passar o parametro para saber a opção que meu usuario fez ?
Obrigado

á consegui via appdelegate, queria algo mais simples

Comment: Você esta fazendo a chamada dessa view via código ou usando o storyboard? Edite sua pergunta e poste o trecho do seu código para ajudar nas respostas

Comment: Via código. Não tenho código... Fiz passando pelo delegate, mas queria outro metodo mais simples...

Comment: Poste o que você já conseguiu fazer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você estiver utilizando a Storyboard simplesmente através do mapeamento da ação é possível saber o qual botão o usuário apertou no momento.
Caso os botões estiverem sendo alocados programaticamente, há a possibilidade de criar uma ação para o botão, que levarão para métodos distintos, através de Selector. Igualmente a Storyboard utiliza o mesmo argumento de Selector para mapear uma ação de um botão.
Pode-se utilizar no caso da delegate, as Tags para identificar cada botão, facilitando quando é chamado o método delegate.

Espero ter ajudado.